# detect an undefined item in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do you detect an undefined item in jQuery in an 'if statement' I have tried something like below without any success so far.

```
 success: function(data){

  if(typeof data.DATA[0].RECIPIENTID = 'undefined'){
     // do nothing                          
   }
   else {
       //else get value
       console.log(data.DATA[0].RECIPIENTID);                       
   }


 console.log(data);

 }
});
```

Comment: This is a JavaScript (language) question, not a jQuery (library) one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`=` is an assigment operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators) in JavaScript. [Use `===`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators), not `=`.

```
if(typeof data.DATA[0].RECIPIENTID === 'undefined'){
    // ...
}
// ...
```

See also [Which equals operator (== vs ===) should be used in JavaScript comparisons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/javascript-vs-does-it-matter-which-equal-operator-i-use)

Answer (score 1):

undefined does not need quotes ''

```
    if(RECIPIENTID === undefined){
     // do nothing                          
   alert("undefined");
}
```

Comment: Careful with this one, `undefined` needn't be undefined: `(function(undefined,foo){console.log(foo === undefined); console.log(undefined);})('bar')` paste this in your console

Comment: Compare that to: `(function(foo,undefined){console.log(foo === undefined); console.log(undefined);})(undefined,'bar')` and `(function(foo,undefined){console.log(foo === undefined); console.log(undefined);})()`

Comment: I still get TypeError: data.DATA[0] is undefined
[Break On This Error]  

if(data.DATA[0].RECIPIENTID === undefined){  -- any idea why?